# Babel: Can't load CSS (unexpected token) when using AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, aws-amplify, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I'm building a React app with AWS Amplify.

I unit test my app using [RITEway](https://github.com/ericelliott/riteway). To use RITEway with React, I have to install `@babel/core @babel/polyfill @babel/preset-env @babel/register` and then run the tests with:

```
"test": "riteway -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-color"
```

The `.babelrc` is defined as follows:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

I've connected a component to graphql using AWS Amplify and it's AppSync helper methods:

```
export default compose(
  graphqlMutation(gql(createContact), gql(listContacts), 'Contact'),
)(CreateContactButton);
```

This button is being rendered as a child component in one of the tests. This test crashes now saying that there is a `client` missing in the context of the component, which I fix by wrapping it in a `<ApolloProvider />` in the test file:

```
describe('ContactList component', async assert => {
  const createContactList = (props = {}) =>
    render(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ContactList {...props} />
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
```

As soon as I do that, the tests fails with:

```
/Users/jan/dev/myapp/node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css:13
:root {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/jan/dev/myapp/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
```

I can't change the Amplify code. What other babel plugins do I need to add to avoid my tests crashing when encountering CSS? Or, more generally, how can I avoid babel this babel crash and get my tests to run?

Comment: I'm running the same error, seeking desperately for solution. Please add a solution if you find one 

Answer (score 0):

Babel can not process resources like CSS or image files. But the @babel/register package will provide a way to configure custom loaders by extension. They can be assessed after the @babel/register package has been imported. It will overwrite the original require from node with the require from babel. There is a settings object `extensions` on `require` available to set the custom loader. To ignore some extension just set the loader for the extension to an empty function like this:

```js
require.extensions['.css'] = () => {};
```

In combination with RITEway an additional file with a name like `babelInit.js` and some configuration like this can be used to ignore CSS and JPG image files:

```js
require('@babel/register');
require('@babel/polyfill');

require.extensions['.css'] = () => {};
require.extensions['.jpg'] = () => {};
```

Finally require the new configuration file instead of the packages it self:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "riteway -r ./babelInit.js 'src/**/*.test.js' | tap-color"
  }
}
```